# Finding limit as $x \rightarrow 0$

Tags: calculus, limits

The question asks to find

> $$\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\sin x^n}{\left(\sin x\right)^m} \;\;\;\forall\; m<n$$

I solved it by applying the L'Hopital rule since it is of the form $\frac{0}{0}$ and then once I differentiated we get $$\lim_{x \rightarrow0}       \left(\frac{\frac{d \sin x^n}{dx}}{\frac{ \left(d \sin x \right)^m}{dx}}\right),
$$ 
which gives us
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow0} \frac{n\cos x \cdot x^{n-1}}{\left(m \sin x\right)^{m-1} \cos x}.
$$
Now this gives us a function of the form $$\frac{n x^{n-1}}{\left(m \sin x\right)^{m-1}},
$$ 
which means that since $n>m$ now, we can keep differentiating the denominator and we will eventually get something of the form $\frac{0}{k}$ which means the limit must be $0$. 
This is how I have gone about it. I have $2$ questions:
$1.$ Is there a better method than this to solve it?
$2.$ Can we find out the limit of this function if $m>n$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write the function as follows:

$$ \frac{ \sin x^n }{  x^n } \cdot \frac{x^m}{\sin^m x} \cdot x^{n-m}$$

Now, in the limit we obtain $1 \cdot 1^m \cdot 0 = 0 $ since $n-m>0$. We have used the elementary fact that

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ \sin x }{x} = 1 $$

Answer (score 1):

> $$\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\sin x^n}{\left(\sin x\right)^m} \;\;\;\forall\; m<n$$

$$= \lim \limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^n (1 - \frac{x^{2n}}{3!}\dots)}{x^m[ 1 - \frac{x^2}{3!} \dots]^m} = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow0} x^{n-m} =0$$

By the way, $\sin x = x = \frac {x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} \dots$

and $\cos x = 1 - \frac {x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} \dots$